# Android: MapView obtain max zoom level for point

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have mapview activity which display some overlay items. I should set max available zoom level for overlay points. zoomToSpan work perfectly if i have some overlays, but if i have one overlay with cords 0,0 it try to zoom in to max zoom level 22 and show black screen because Google map can't displayed details for this zoom level. How can i obtain max zoom level for current cords which google map can display. Thank you. I forgot, i try this:

```
GeoPoint curPoint = new GeoPoint((iLatitudeMax + iLatitudeMin) >> 1, (iLongtitudeMax + iLongtitudeMin) >> 1);

        MapController mapcontroller = mapView.getController();
        if(mapcontroller != null && curPoint != null) {
            mapcontroller.zoomToSpan(Math.abs(iLatitudeMax - iLatitudeMin), Math.abs(iLongtitudeMax - iLongtitudeMin));
            mapcontroller.setCenter(curPoint);
            int zoomLevel = mapView.getZoomLevel();
            zoomLevel = (zoomLevel > mapView.getMaxZoomLevel()) ? mapView.getMaxZoomLevel() - 1 : zoomLevel;
            mapcontroller.setZoom(zoomLevel);
            mapcontroller.animateTo(curPoint);
        }
```